# PHP: Error in mockery

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I have just started using php mockery following the Jeffery way book "Jeffrey Way Laravel Testing Decoded", but I encountered problem on my first mock. I have been looking at it can't seem to find the problem.

```
<?php
namespace BB8\Tests;

use BB8\App\Generator;
use BB8\App\File;
use Mockery;
class GeneratorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMockery()
    {
        $mockedFile = Mockery::mock(File::class);
        $mockedFile->shouldReceive('put')
                    ->with('foo.txt', 'foo bar bar')
                    ->once();
        $generator = new Generator($mockedFile);
        $generator->fire();
    }
}
```

The error thrown is

```
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found 
for Mockery_0_BB8_App_File::put("foo.txt", "foo bar"). 
Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched 
no expected argument list for this method
```

I have all the methods implemented yet it does not work.

I need help, can't seem to find out what the problem is.

Generator Class

```
namespace BB8\App;

class Generator
{
  protected $file;

  public function __construct(File $file)
  {
    $this->file = $file;
  }

  protected function getContent()
  {
    return 'foo bar';
  }

  public function fire()
  {
    $content = $this->getContent();
    $this->file->put('foo.txt', $content);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of the `Generator` class?

Comment: @Matteo added Generator class

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
public function testMockery()
{
    $mockedFile = Mockery::mock(File::class);
    $mockedFile->shouldReceive('put')
                ->with('foo.txt', 'foo bar bar')
                ->once();
    $generator = new Generator($mockedFile);
    $generator->fire();
}
```

to this:

```
public function testMockery()
{
    $mockedFile = Mockery::mock(File::class);
    $mockedFile->shouldReceive('put')
                ->with('foo.txt', 'foo bar')
                ->once();
    $generator = new Generator($mockedFile);
    $generator->fire();
}
```

The problem is that `getContent()` will return `'foo bar'`, not `'foo bar bar'` and therefore your expectation for `put` will fail because the input parameters don't match.

Comment: Did this solve your problem or were there other issues?